# Prioritizing jobs on Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, queue, sidekiq

Imagine a simple dating app, which provides you a potential match every day. When users first sign up, the following happens -

1. They are sent an email - "Welcoming to the Dating app!"
2. A custom matching job kicks off to find them a match for the day and sends them an email - "You have a match!"

If I choose to mass-enroll several thousand people, the job queue will be populated with several thousand jobs of both #1 and #2. It's important that they receive the email *first* before getting a match, since otherwise it makes for a confusing experience.

I have -

```
# config/sidekiq.rb
:queues:
  - high_priority
  - default
  - low_priority
```

As per [this page](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options), those queues should process in the listed order.

1. How does this prioritization work? Is the *entire* `high priority` queue drained before picking an item of the `default` or `low_priority` queues? Or is it just checked more often, still allowing some lower priority jobs to be processed at the same time?
2. As a follow-up to #1, is there a way to ensure that *for a specific user*, they receive the welcome email before they receive their match email? The former will be in the `high_priority` queue and the latter in the `default` priority, but there's no guarantee either queue is in any particular order for users.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time Sidekiq looks for a job in Redis, it will check high_priority first, then default, then low_priority.  The jobs in default will just sit there as long as there are jobs in high_priority.

Comment: So If I have concurrency set 10 and 10 Jobs are in Busy state for default queue and if the new job gets added to high_priority then would it pick a job from high_priority queue and put those 10 jobs on hold?